# Migration with a decimal number with 2 trailing digits

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-migrations

```
Rails 3.2
MySQL gem
```

I have the following in my migration:

```
t.decimal :pre_tax_total, default: nil, scale: 2
t.decimal :post_tax_total, default: nil, scale: 2
```

Based on what I read, scale:2 will produce a decimal with 2 trailing digits.

When I run the migration, and look at the table structure, I see the following:

```
pre_tax_total   decimal(10,0) 
post_tax_total  decimal(10,0)
```

Which means the values are getting truncated by the MySQL server. What is the ActiveRecord syntax to create these columns as decimal(10,2)?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

That would be:

```
t.decimal :pre_tax_total, precision: 10, scale: 2
```

Although [Rails 3 Migrations Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2/migrations.html) skips it, the description is available in the [source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/c1e38d68a2b1fcf1dd49c3bd58a604b928cd1234/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb#L498-L510):

> ```
>   # Note: The precision is the total number of significant digits,
>   # and the scale is the number of digits that can be stored following
>   # the decimal point. For example, the number 123.45 has a precision of 5
>   # and a scale of 2. A decimal with a precision of 5 and a scale of 2 can
>   # range from -999.99 to 999.99.
>   #
>   # Please be aware of different RDBMS implementations behavior with
>   # <tt>:decimal</tt> columns:
>   # * The SQL standard says the default scale should be 0, <tt>:scale</tt> <=
>   #   <tt>:precision</tt>, and makes no comments about the requirements of
>   #   <tt>:precision</tt>.
>   # * MySQL: <tt>:precision</tt> [1..63], <tt>:scale</tt> [0..30].
>   #   Default is (10,0).
> ```

The last line partly explains why you got `decimal(10,0)`.

Comment: It worked. Thank you. I could swear that the doc said that you could skip the precision param

Comment: And you can do this through the command line generator with `rails g migration add_pre_tax_total_to_your_table_name pre_tax_total:decimal{10-2}`.

Answer (score 1):

Rails 4.0 and above supports generating migration with decimal precision and scale.

`bin/rails generate migration AddPriceToProducts 'price:decimal{5,2}'`